# Unity3D rendering only some triangles in a mesh - and triangle fans?

Tags: unity, mesh

In my OpenGL apps, one of my tricks that I've used often for displaying heads up displays and ui elements, is to have a sorted mesh of triangles and then only render a portion of them.

In one game I have a circular fuel gauge.  I made a mesh of triangles using a triangle fan that spans around the circle.  In code I can limit the number of triangles that it's drawing to make the fuel gauge appear at that % of fuel.

So in this example I take the % of fuel left, multiply by the number of segments in the fan, and then draw it:

```
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, (int)remainingFuel+1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *) (0 * sizeof(GLuint)));
```

If 50% of the fuel is left it draws 50% of the triangles in the fan which appears to be half the circle shape.

Can this easily be replicated in Unity3D?  Where I can limit the range of triangles of a mesh that will render to a specific start and stop range?

Does Unity3D even do triangle fans?

Or do I need to figure out a new way to do this?

By the way I do know how to create procedural meshes in unity code (C#) but am still fairly new to Unity.  I know I could store the entire mesh in one class and then copy only a portion of it to a game object based on the fuel level.  I'd rather not create a new version of the mesh for each frame because the fuel is constantly changing.  It seems more efficient to just limit the count on a non-changing mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manipulating meshes in Unity, I'd use a Shader instead. 
It gives you more control over the appearance of your gauge and will perform better.

For starters, you could use the built-in alpha cutoff shader and use a circular gradient as your cutoff ramp. Something like this should do the trick:

[image: Circular gradient]

Then you can manipulate the cutoff value like this:

```
renderer.material.SetFloat("_Cutoff", myCutOffValue);
```

where `myCutOffValue` is a float ranging from `0` to `1`.

**Update:**

As requested in the comments, here's a shader-example that uses two textures. One for RGBA and the other for the cutoff. You can create a new shader in Unity and replace the automatically generated code with the following:

```
Shader "Custom/SeparateCutout" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CutTex ("Cutout Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
        }
        LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Lambert alpha

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _CutTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
        float _Cutoff;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float2 uv_CutTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            fixed4 cut = tex2D(_CutTex, IN.uv_CutTex);
            clip(cut.a - _Cutoff);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
    ENDCG
    }

    Fallback "Transparent/VertexLit"
}
```

You'll find this shader under `Custom` > `SeparateCutout` in the shaders dropdown. For the cutout texture, I recommend you set it to `Alpha 8` (available under `Format`, when you switch the Texture type to "Advanced". Use "Alpha from Grayscale" setting if necessary). That way you'll save some GPU memory.

Comment: Looks like that shader only has 1 source texture. My texture already has transparency. So I'll need to write my own shader to use two textures.  Hmmm...  Or do the cutoff in code via a uniform variable. Hmmm...

Comment: @badweasel You can download all built-in shaders from the [download archive page](http://unity3d.com/unity/download/archive). Then modify the shader according to your needs... I'll have a look and update the answer with an example for a separate cutout texture.

Comment: Since my first need of this is not a circle but just a box I was considering using per vertex colors to make a cutoff varying. But then I have to add vertex colors to the verts of a sprite. If I use a texture can it be another sprite on the same sprite sheet?  Or would it have to have the same uv.  Obviously performance is important as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update with code. Wish I could give you a second check mark. Is there a way to use different uv for the cut off texture?

Comment: SWEET! Got it working.  Thanks!  My modification was to add an offset uv property, offset the main uv by this amount, and then did `fixed4 cut = tex2D(_MainTex, uv_OffsetCoord);`  Since my thing is on a sprite sheet and my cutoff gradient was next to the thing.

Comment: Glad you made it work. I think adding another UV Input for the `CutTex` should work as well and won't break whenever your sprite-sheet changes. I'll update the answer accordingly.